# JQuery to click on Browse when Input field is added dynamically with ajax not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am having issues having `jQuery-click` on the browse button. Here is a sample of my code. My code basically dynamically adds an input field (in ajax) and I want the input field to be "Clicked" on after it is added but it doesn't work properly. It works if it is ran twice but it is always the previous input browse field that is clicked on, not the current.

```
 $( document ).delegate( ".add_picture", "click", function() {
    //$('.add_picture').click(function(){
        //Check and see if there is a selected question
        if (isAnythingHighlighted()){
            var assessmentID = $('#assessment_name_input').attr("data-assessmentid");
            var questionID = $('.highlight').attr("data-questionid");
            var order = $(".highlight ul li").length;
            var addQuestionItem=true;
            var questionItemTypeID = 3; //3 for picture
            if (debug) 
            {
               alert(questionID);
            } 
            jQuery.ajax({
                type: "POST", // HTTP method POST or GET
                url: "create_assessment_response.php", //Where to make Ajax calls
                dataType:"text", // Data type, HTML, json etc.
                data:{
                        addQuestionItem:addQuestionItem, 
                        questionID:questionID, 
                        questionItemTypeID:questionItemTypeID, 
                        order:order, 
                        assessmentID:assessmentID
                }, //Form variables
                success:function(response){
                        response = response.trim();
                        //Code for the Picture li
                        var li = 
                                $("\<li class='pictureItem' data-questionItemUniqueID='" + response + "'>\
                                    <a class='deleteQuestionItem'>\
                                    <i class='remove_icon fa fa-remove'></i></a>\
                                    <h2>Image</h2>\
                                    <div class='wrap'>\
                                    <form action='ajaxupload.php' method='post' enctype='multipart/form-data'>\
                                    <img style='display:none' class='loader' src='loader.gif' alt='Loading....' title='Loading....' />\
                                    <input id='browse"+response+"' class='uploadImage' type='file' accept='image/*' name='image' />\
                                    <input class='imageSubmit' type='submit' value='Upload' data-questionItemUniqueID='" + response + "'>\
                                    <div class='preview' style=''></div>\
                                    </form>\
                                    </div>\
                                    </li>");
                        //Add the li to the highlighted question
                        $(".highlight ul").append(li);
                        makeSubListSortable();
                        $.getUpdatedLog();
                        //$(".highlight ul").children('li').find('input[type=file]').trigger("click"); this won't work. Auto open file browse.

                        // $(".highlight ul").children('li:first').find('input[type=file]').click();

                   },
                   error:function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError){
                         alert(thrownError);
                   }
        });
        //end ajax 
}


$(".highlight ul").children('li.pictureItem:last').find("input[type=file]").trigger("click");
});
//example appended Li code: <li class="pictureItem" data-questionitemuniqueid="7515">            <a class="deleteQuestionItem">            <i class="remove_icon fa fa-remove"></i>            </a>            <h2>Image</h2>            <div class="wrap">            <form action="ajaxupload.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">            <img style="display:none" class="loader" src="loader.gif" alt="Loading...." title="Loading....">            <input id="browse7515" class="uploadImage" accept="image/*" name="image" type="file">            <input class="imageSubmit" value="Upload" data-questionitemuniqueid="7515" type="submit">            <div class="preview" style=""></div>            </form>            </div>            </li>
```

Comment: **[Works fine here](https://jsfiddle.net/Guruprasad_Rao/1b2kLpL5/)**. May be you are having some console errors.. What is the `response` in the above code.. Please try to attach complete code..

Comment: It must be a problem within Ajax, but the response part is working as intended.

Comment: Why have you commented that `trigger` inside `success`? Did you try that there? Also did you check for any console errors?

Comment: To clarify, my ajax is working, but this last part to click on the input(browse) does not work until the button has been clicked more than once, it doesn't seem to recognize that there is an input[type=file] until after the entire code has been ran

Comment: no console errors, the code doesn't work at all where i commented it out inside success (even though the other code in success is working)

Comment: Ok.. Does that append `li`? Cross verify all the attributes in the browser and if possible post the relevant `html` too and sample `response`..

Comment: the li does get appended. I will add code of appended Li.

Comment: Also if possible sample `response`.. I will try to replicate..

Comment: my response is just a number, like 1234

Comment: I added some example code of the appended LI that gets added, sorry for the poor formatting

Comment: Try placing your `trigger-click` before `makeSubListSortable();
                        $.getUpdatedLog();`

Comment: Hmm, it wasn't that. I even tried commenting out those two functions. When the trigger-click is there it doesn't work at all

Comment: Not sure whether this is the case.. But if you see your rendered elements input does not have self closing tags..

Comment: Hmm, I was missing a closing tag but that wasn't the issue.

Answer (score 1):

I found a temporary solution. Using this setTimeout seems to work.

```
           setTimeout(function(){
  $(".highlight ul").children('li.pictureItem:last').find("input[type=file]").trigger("click");
}, 300);
```